# Can a sample space consist of an infinite amount of outcomes?

Tags: probability

I began studying probability theory for the first time not too long ago and thus far all problems have involved finite sample spaces. Can someone give me an example of a problem where the sample space is infinite? Does such a problem even exist?

Comment: Toss a fair coin until a Head appears for the first time. The sample space is $$\Omega = \{H, TH, TTH, \ldots, T^{n-1}H, \ldots \}$$ which has a countable number of elements in it. Note that there is an outcome in $\Omega$ for each integer $0, 1, 2, \ldots, n, \ldots$.

Comment: Great example, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about dropping a pin randomly anywhere on the interval $(0,1)$ to get an uncountably infinite number of outcomes?

Comment: The pin has a finite width and therefore it will not be pointing to an infinite number of rational numbers (that which we can mark on a physical object). Am I missing something? I was trying to think of real life examples of infinite sample spaces too and the problem is we measure everything approximately. Even a computer can't generate a random number out of infinite possibilities.

Comment: @Aditya the pin is obviously a theoretical one, having a point width. As for ability to *pick* from an infinite space - that requires the axiom of choice